# Finding concrete examples of open coverings

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

Hello, everyone I'm struggling to find an open covering of R containing two subsets and a countable covering of R which does not contain a finite sub covering.

Facts I know: I know an open covering for a set A, is a collection of open sets whose union contains A.  A sub cover is a sub collection of O, whose union contains A.
I know a set is said to be compact if every open cover has a finite sub cover.

Thoughts
for part b: I can think of an uncountable covering of R which does not contain a finite sub covering.  Namely, Ua=(-a+1,a+1) for each a that is an element of R.  However, I cannot think of a countable covering of R.

for part a: I can thinking of an open covering of R.  However, I am really struggling with this one, as I cannot think of an open covering of R containing exactly 2 subsets.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For part (a), try 
$$\{ (-1,\infty), (-\infty, 1) \}.$$

For part (b), try 
$$\{ (-n,n):n\in\mathbb{N} \}.$$